# How to write this MySQL bit in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku, geolocation

I'm looking at this [tidbit from MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/csv)

```
SELECT ip_country
FROM geoip
WHERE
INET_ATON('xxx.xx.xxx.xxx') BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num
LIMIT 1
```

I tried it a couple of ways and it doesn't seem like BETWEEN does what I think it does in postgresql.

As you can see, I'm trying to determine the country based on an IP. Here's a couple of rows in case this can be done easier:

> "223.204.0.0","223.207.255.255","3754688512","3754950655","TH","Thailand" "223.208.0.0","223.215.255.255","3754950656","3755474943","CN","China"
>   "223.216.0.0","223.219.255.255","3755474944","3755737087","JP","Japan"

The postgres version is 9.1 - forgot to add this.

Comment: It should go without saying that we need the table definition to tell for sure. Add your version of PostgreSQL while being at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type [`inet`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) would probably solve your problem. As long as the column type is `text` or `varchar`, the data is ordered like text according to your [collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS) - which also affects `BETWEEN`.

Also depends on the version of PostgreSQL (collation support is a late addition). It's all guesswork as long as you don't provide basic information.